# NSDateFormatter does not make sense

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter

I have the following date: month = December, day = 01,  year = 2011. The date is given as an NSString with the following format "111201" (YYMMdd). Now I want to parse this string into a NSDate object with a NSDateFormatter:

```
self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYMMdd"];
NSDate* date = [self.dateFormatter dateFromString:strDate];
```

And the output of "111201" is "2011-11-30 23:00:00 +0000". That doesn't make sense to me.

How is this possible? I'd expect "2011-12-01 23:00:00 +0000".

Comment: It looks like you are reading in a date without time information, so it's assuming a certain base time and then applying a timezone offset. What timezone is your local time set to?

Comment: timezone difference does not lead to a difference of a month.

Comment: @samfisher - the difference between the two dates is only a day at the most, this is quite probably a timeline issue.

Comment: @samfisher the difference is 1 hour. The OP is probably at GMT+1.

Comment: Yes that's right. I'm GMT+1 since I'm in Europe/Berlin.

Comment: @toom then, as others have said, there is no problem here. The date formatter is correctly assuming your local timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you display NSDate objects in the debugger or output their values via NSLog they are always shown as GMT dates and times (that's what the +0000 at the end means).

Your local time zone appears to be '+0100' (Western Europe?) so the date formatter is operating on 'December 01 2011 00:00am +0100' and creating an NSDate correctly. But at the point of display the NSDate (which is just a single point in time with no timezone information) is shown in GMT - and the equivalent is one hour earlier i.e. 'November 30 2011 23:00pm +0000'.

If you really want to convert '111201' to 'December 01 2011 00:00am +0000' then set the date formatter's timezone to GMT like this:

```
self.dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

Comment: That makes sense. So there is no real problem at all. Only the output of the NSDate description displays the "wrong" date?

Comment: Exactly - except it's not the 'wrong' date - 'December 01 2011 00:00am +0100' is completely equivalent to  'November 30 2011 23:00pm +0000'.

Comment: In summary - NSDates are timezone-neutral. You just have to be careful at the points of conversion (string-to-date or date-to-string) to take time zones into account.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your date formatter to correct the time zone off of GMT:

```
self.dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Just as setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone], setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] does not make any difference.

Comment: Bummer.  What if you explicitly set the time to 00:00:00 during the conversion?